# Elasticsearch pyspark connection in insecure mode

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, curl, pyspark, elasticsearch-hadoop

My end goal is to insert data from hdfs to elasticsearch but the issue i am facing is the connectivity

I am able to connect to my elasticsearch node using below curl command

`curl -u username -X GET https://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:9200/_cat/indices?v' --insecure`

but when it comes to connection with spark I am unable to do so. My command to insert data is
`df.write.mode("append").format('org.elasticsearch.spark.sql').option("es.net.http.auth.user", "username").option("es.net.http.auth.pass", "password").option("es.index.auto.create","true").option('es.nodes', 'https://xx.xxx.xx.xxx').option('es.port','9200').save('my-index/my-doctype')`

Error i am getting is

```
org.elastisearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException:Cannot detect ES version - typical this happens if then network/Elasticsearch cluster is not accessible or when targetting a Wan/Cloud instance without the proper setting 'es.nodes.wan.only'
....
....
Caused by: org.elasticseach.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopNoNodesLeftException: Connection error (check network and/or proy settings)- all nodes failed; tried [[xx.xxx.xx.xxx:9200]]
....
...
```

Here, What would be the pyspark equivalent of  curl --insecure

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many attempt and different config options. I found a way how to connect elastisearch running on https insecurely

```
        dfToEs.write.mode("append").format('org.elasticsearch.spark.sql') \
        .option("es.net.http.auth.user", username) \
        .option("es.net.http.auth.pass", password) \
        .option("es.net.ssl", "true") \
        .option("es.net.ssl.cert.allow.self.signed", "true") \
        .option("mergeSchema", "true") \
        .option('es.index.auto.create', 'true') \
        .option('es.nodes', 'https://{}'.format(es_ip)) \
        .option('es.port', '9200') \
        .option('es.batch.write.retry.wait', '100s') \
        .save('{index}/_doc'.format(index=index))
```

with the

```
(es.net.ssl, true)
```

We also have to provide self signed certificate like below

```
(es.net.ssl.cert.allow.self.signed, true)
```

Answer (score 1):

I did check a lot of things and finally i can write in AWS ElasticSearch service (ES), but with scala/spark.

1. In a VPC, create security groups to access from EMR to ES with port 443 (inbound rules in ES to SG of EMR and inbound rules in EMR to same port)
2. Check connectivity from EMR master node, with a telnet command

```sh
    telnet xyz.eu-west-1.es.amazonaws.com 443
```

3. Once check above, check app level with curl command

   ````sh
   curl https://xyz.eu-west-1.es.amazonaws.com:443/domainname/_search?pretty=true&?q=*```
   ````
4. After, goes to the code, in my case i did test with spark-shell, but server confs was included in start like this:

   ```
    spark-shell --jars elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11-7.1.1.jar --conf spark.es.nodes="xyz.eu-west-1.es.amazonaws.com" --conf spark.es.port=443 --conf spark.es.nodes.wan.only=true --conf spark.es.nodes.discovery="false" --conf spark.es.index.auto.create="true" --conf spark.es.resource="domain/doc" --conf spark.es.scheme="https"
   ```

   5. Finally the code to write:

   ````scala
   import java.util.Date
   import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Dataset, SparkSession}
   import org.elasticsearch.spark._
   import org.elasticsearch.spark.sql._
   val dateformat =  new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
   val currentdate = dateformat.format(new Date)
   val colorsDF = spark.read.json("multilinecolors.json")
   val mcolors = colorsDF.withColumn("Date",lit(currentdate))
   mcolors.write.mode("append").format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql").option("es.net.http.auth.user", "").option("es.net.http.auth.pass", "").option("es.net.ssl", "true").option("es.net.ssl.cert.allow.self.signed", "true").option("mergeSchema", "true").option("es.index.auto.create", "true").option("es.nodes","https://xyz.eu-west-1.es.amazonaws.com").option("es.port", "443").option("es.batch.write.retry.wait", "100").save("domainname/_doc")```
   ````

Comment: `     .option("spark.es.scheme", "https")`
solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

can you try with the below sparkConfs,

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
.set("spark.es.index.auto.create", "true")
.set("spark.es.nodes", "yourESaddress")
.set("spark.es.port", "9200")
.set("spark.es.net.http.auth.user","")
.set("spark.es.net.http.auth.pass", "")
.set("spark.es.resource", indexName)
.set("spark.es.nodes.wan.only", "true")
```

still you face the problem then, `es.net.ssl = true` and see.

If still you get the error try adding the below configs,

```
'es.resource' = 'ctrl_rater_resumen_lla/hb',
'es.nodes' = 'localhost',
'es.port' = '9200',
'es.index.auto.create' = 'true',
'es.index.read.missing.as.empty' = 'true',
'es.nodes.discovery'='true',
'es.net.ssl'='false'
'es.nodes.client.only'='false',
'es.nodes.wan.only' = 'true'
'es.net.http.auth.user'='xxxxx',
'es.net.http.auth.pass' = 'xxxxx'
'es.nodes.discovery' = 'false'
```